# in ASP.NET page JQuery Tabs controls Validation issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am using JQuery tab in my ASP.NET application. While changing from one tab to another tab, .NET validation is not happening or if details entered in mandotory field also, its validating.

Please someone help in this regard..

Comment: please eloborate the question..

Comment: Thanks for the reply..

I have jquery tabs in my page. In both tabs I have controls like dropdownlist, textbox etc.. If I change tab from 1 to 2 means Page 2 some controls are not validating. If I refresh the page controls validates or if I directly load page to that tab means controls will validates perfectly. But while changing between tabs controls not validating. 

Please let me know if anything is required.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Hi. any one having solution for this..